# Problems passing arguments from Python to C

Tags: python, c, types, setup.py

I've made an C extension to Python. I have a problem when I call `writeByte(..)` from python. Whatever number I put in as argument in python, the value will be zero when I print it in the C function.

test.py:

```
import myTest_1024LS
myTest_1024LS.findInterface()
myTest_1024LS.writeByte(0x01, 0x43)
```

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

module1 = Extension('myTest_1024LS', 
include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include'], 
libraries = ['hid'], 
library_dirs = ['/usr/local/include', '/Home/NetBeansProjects/MCCDAQ/usb1024LS_with_py'],
sources = [ 'pmd.c', 'usb-1024LS.c', 'myTest_1024LS.c'],
language = 'c', )

setup (name = 'myTest_1024LS',
   ext_modules = [module1])
```

myTest_1024LS.c:

```
void findInterface(void){
int interface;
hid_return ret;
ret = hid_init();
if (ret != HID_RET_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "hid_init failed with return code %d\n", ret);
        exit(1);
}

if ((interface = PMD_Find_Interface(&hid, 0, USB1024LS_PID)) >= 0) {
        printf("USB 1024LS Device is found! interface = %d\n", interface);
} else if ((interface = PMD_Find_Interface(&hid, 0, USB1024HLS_PID)) >= 0) {
        printf("USB 1024HLS Device is found! interface = %d\n", interface);
} else {
        fprintf(stderr, "USB 1024LS and USB 1024HLS not found.\n");
        exit(1);
}
}

void writeByte(__u8 port, __u8 byte){
printf("%x, %x\n", port, byte);
if((port==DIO_PORTA)||(port==DIO_PORTB)){       
    usbDOut_USB1024LS(hid, port, byte);
    printf("You wrote 0x%x to port %x\n", byte, port);
}else if(port == DIO_PORTC){
    printf("Port C is splitted into PORT C HIGH and LOW,\nthis means that your byte is separated into two nibbles before sending\n");
    __u8 nib_low = byte & 0x0F;
    __u8 nib_high = (byte & 0xF0)>>4;
    usbDOut_USB1024LS(hid, DIO_PORTC_LOW, nib_low);
    usbDOut_USB1024LS(hid, DIO_PORTC_HI, nib_high);
}else{
    printf("Port is not intended for bytes\n");
    exit(1);
}
}

PyDoc_STRVAR(myTest_1024LS__doc__, "myTes_1024LS point evaluation kernel");
PyDoc_STRVAR(findInterface__doc__, "find device");
PyDoc_STRVAR(writeByte__doc__, "write byte");

static PyMethodDef myTest_methods[] = {
{"findInterface", py_findInterface, METH_VARARGS, findInterface__doc__},
{"writeByte", py_writeByte, METH_VARARGS, writeByte__doc__}, 
{NULL, NULL}
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC initmyTest_1024LS(void){
Py_InitModule3("myTest_1024LS", myTest_methods, myTest_1024LS__doc__);

}

static PyObject *py_findInterface(PyObject *self, PyObject *args){

if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "")){
    return NULL;
}
findInterface();
return Py_BuildValue("i",0);
}

static PyObject *py_writeByte(PyObject *self, PyObject *args){
__u8 port=1, byte=4;
if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "dd|i:writeByte", &port, &byte)){
    return NULL;
}
writeByte((__u8)port, (__u8)byte);
return Py_BuildValue("i",0);
}
```

As you can see In the writeByte function, I print port and byte value as the first thing, to check of the values are correct. So far they have always been zero when they are really different from zero. 
I have also tried to put decimal values instead of hex values as arguments, but didnt seem to help.

It is probably some data type problem, but I cant find it...

The **C** code have been tested in a **C** main function before I started this python/c project.

Comment: You are using `PyArg_ParseTuple()` incorrectly. You are expecting two mandatory `double` arguments and one optional `int` argument. That's not what you seem to really need.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I just use "ii" instead, of course... Then it worked, great:)

Comment: Can we please have that as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

@The Paramagnetic Croissant wrote in a comment:

> You are using `PyArg_ParseTuple()` incorrectly. You are expecting two mandatory `double` arguments and one optional `int` argument. That's not what you seem to really need.

The OP wrote:

> Ah, thanks! I just use "ii" instead, of course... Then it worked

Comment: ([Answered in a comment and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments).)